# Dash Python: Activate a different tab using a link

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a multi tab dash app. I want to place a hyperlink on one tab, clicking which should take me to another tab. What I am trying to do -

```
tab1_content = dbc.Markdown('''
### This is Tab 1    
''')

tab2_content = dbc.Markdown('''
### This is Tab 2    
[Take me to Tab1](#Tab1)
''')
 dbc.Tabs([
    dbc.Tab([tab1_content],id = 'Tab1',label = 'Tab 1'),
    dbc.Tab([tab2_content],id = 'Tab2',label = 'Tab 2'),
    ])
```

I have tried adding an anchor using html.A() on tab 1. That did not help either. Let me know if there is any way of getting this done.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe `dbc.Markdown` should be replaced with `dcc.Markdown`.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the state of your components in a callback based on URI fragment. You require [`dcc.Location`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/location) component to do so. And in case of [`dbc.Tabs`](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/tabs/) to manage `active_tab` you have to set `tab_id` property for each `dbc.Tab`. Here is the sample:

```py
from dash import dcc, ctx, Input, Output, no_update

# location component to be included into the layout:
location = dcc.Location('url')

# Need all dependant components here to prevent an infinite callback loop
@dash.callback(
    Output('url', 'hash'),
    Output('tabs', 'active_tab'),
    Input('url', 'hash'),
    Input('tabs', 'active_tab'),
    config_prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
def handle_navigation(fragment, tab_id):

    triggered_by_location = (dash.ctx.triggered_id == 'url')

    if triggered_by_location:

        # TODO: Add necessary validations here or more complex unpacking
        new_tab_id = fragment[1:]

        return no_update, new_tab_id

    # TODO: Add more complex state encoding if required
    new_fragment = f"#{tab_id}"
    
    return new_fragment, no_update
```